# assistance with passing variable to bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do something which i think many people have done; and have read some examples etc; and have tried to piece together what i need but not having any luck.  What I am trying to do is have a button pass a variable to a bootstrap modal.  And then somehow echo or print the variable within the modal so i know it is working.  I built some code from examples I found

here is my button:

```
<button data-target="#upload-images-modal" data-toggle="modal" class="button upload-images-button"  data-yourParameter="<?php echo $image_id; ?>">Upload Images
             </button>
```

I was not sure if i could echo the image id for the variable to be passed but have done a lot of stuff like that before so seems like it would be ok (this could be an issue though)

Secondly - here is my modal:

```
<div id="upload-images-modal" class="modal fade"  tabindex="-1"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="upload-images-modalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close text-button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="upload-images-modalLabel">Upload Images</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
       ok ok ok

<script>
$('#upload-images-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
 var yourParameter = e.relatedTarget.dataset.yourparameter;
  // Do some stuff w/ it.
 alert(yourParameter);

 });

 </script>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="button">Add Images</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

A couple of notes on this.  I was really uncertain where the script should be "placed" in relation to the modal.  So I just placed in the modal body.

I tried to do an alert to see the variable that was passed.  Nothing is happening though.  So I am hoping someone can give me some pointers on what I am doing wrong.

Thanks so much,

Gerard

Comment: `console.log(e.relatedTarget.dataset)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue could be down to using a early version of bootstrap where `relatedTarget` is not passed.

As in regards to your js, put it in the bottom of the body or in a separate js file reference from the bottom of the body and after any libraries, ie jquery and bootstrap.

Here is your code working with the latest bootstap version

```js
$('#upload-images-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e, f, g) {

  var yourParameter = e.relatedTarget.dataset.yourparameter;
  // Do some stuff w/ it.
  alert(yourParameter);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button data-target="#upload-images-modal" data-toggle="modal" class="button upload-images-button" data-yourParameter="test">Upload Images
</button>

<div id="upload-images-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="upload-images-modalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close text-button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="upload-images-modalLabel">Upload Images</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ok ok ok
        <button data-target="#upload-images-modal" data-toggle="modal" class="button upload-images-button" data-yourParameter="<?php echo $image_id; ?>">Upload Images
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="button">Add Images</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3>Standard Selectpickers</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <select class="selectpicker" data-container="body">
          <option>Mustard</option>
          <option>Ketchup</option>
          <option>Relish</option>
        </select>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: thanks; had to mess around with a little but got it to work!